# How to remove selected records in a w2grid (W2UI)

Tags: javascript, w2ui

I want to delete selected records in a grid of the W2UI library, for which I am using w2grid (https://w2ui.com/web/docs/2.0/grid). **My grid is called 'divInfoConfig'**.

I have created a dynamic grid through a JSON.

**What would I like to do?**

I have a button with the removeSelectedRecords() function, which should behave that if I manually select 1 or more than 1 record, hitting the button should remove them.

**How have I tried?**

The function removeSelectedRecords() does the following:

```
function removeSelectedRecords() {
    var sel = w2ui['divInfoConfig'].getSelection();
    console.log('Selection: ' + sel);
    if (sel) {
        delete sel;
    }
    w2ui['divInfoConfig'].refresh();
}
```

The button is as follows:

```
<button class="w2ui-btn" onclick="removeSelectedRecords();">Remove Selected Records</button>
```

**This is what the console log returns**

*Selection: 6,7*

This is because I selected 2 records.

**The problem:**

The button does nothing. It should delete the selected records.

Any idea on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are using the native JS delete operator, I don't know w2ui but it seems they have their native delete method: https://w2ui.com/web/docs/2.0/w2grid.delete - Shouldn't you be using that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the [native JS delete operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete). You should be using [w2ui delete()](https://w2ui.com/web/docs/2.0/w2grid.delete).

So in your case it's:

```
function removeSelectedRecords() {
    var sel = w2ui['divInfoConfig'].getSelection();
    console.log('Selection: ' + sel);
    if (sel) {
        w2ui.grid.delete(sel);
    }
    w2ui['divInfoConfig'].refresh();
}
```